Uniform decay of $J'_{\nu}(x)$ for $x\gg1$
I need a uniform decay estimate for the derivative $J'_{\nu}(x)$
of the Bessel functions.
By `uniform' I mean an estimate independent of $\nu$, at least for a  range of orders like $\nu\ge0$.
For $J_{\nu}$ we have the well known sharp estimate,
with $C$ independent of $\nu$,
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  |J_{\nu}(x)|\le Cx^{-1/3},
  \qquad
  x>1,\quad \nu\ge0.
\end{equation}
The proof is easy: $J_{\nu}$ can be represented  as a multiple of (the real part of)
\begin{equation*}
  I(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{i\phi(t)}dt,
  \qquad
  \phi(t)=x\sin t-\nu t
\end{equation*}
plus another integral with better decay $x^{-1}$. Split
$I$ in 3 pieces
$I= \int_{0}^{\delta}+\int_{\pi-\delta}^{\pi}
  +\int_{\delta}^{\pi-\delta}$.
The first two pieces are trivially bounded by $2\delta$.
In the piece $\int_{\delta}^{\pi-\delta}$ we have
\begin{equation*}
  |\phi''(t)|=x\sin t \gtrsim x \delta
\end{equation*}
and by van der Corput
$|\int_{\delta}^{\pi-\delta}|\lesssim(x \delta)^{-1/2}$.
Summing up
\begin{equation*}
  |I(x)|\lesssim \delta+(x \delta)^{-1/2}
\end{equation*}
and choosing $\delta=x^{-1/3}$ we obtain (1).
Now consider $J'_{\nu}(x)$. Differentiating w.r.to $x$ the
integral representation, the main term to estimate is now
\begin{equation*}
  I'(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{i\phi(t)}\sin t dt.
\end{equation*}
Repeat the previous argument.
The middle piece $\int_{\delta}^{\pi-\delta}$ can be estimated
by $(x \delta)^{-1/2}$ again by van der Corput.
However,
\begin{equation*}
  \left|\int_{0}^{\delta}e^{i\phi(t)}\sin t dt\right|\le
  \int_{0}^{\delta}t dt\le \delta^{2},
\end{equation*}
and similarly $|\int_{\pi-\delta}^{\pi}|\le \delta^{2}$.
Thus we get now
\begin{equation*}
  |I'(x)|\lesssim \delta^{2}+(x \delta)^{-1/2}
\end{equation*}
and choosing $\delta=x^{-1/5}$ we get an unexpected
\begin{equation*}
  |I'(x)|\lesssim x^{-2/5}.
\end{equation*}
The second integral in the representation of $J'_{\nu}$ decays
like $x^{-1}$, so we get a uniform estimate
$|J'_{\nu}(x)|\lesssim x^{-2/5}$. This is a bit surprising, looks false or not sharp.
My question: is this estimate correct? if it is, what is the sharp uniform decay estimate for $J'_\nu$?

I would expect a decay $\propto x^{-1/2}$, consistent with your bound.

It is also my guess, but if this is true it should be so well known that a specialist should point at a good reference in no time. I hope

Please use a high-level tag like "ca.classical-analysis-and-odes". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1075/

I think the issue is that the application of van der Corput for the middle piece is not sharp enough. Note that in the proof of the van der Corput lemma (with the second order derivative bound) we use the standard integration by parts bound away from the critical points of $\phi$. Near the critical points of $\phi$ we use the lower bound on $\phi''$ to get an estimate on the width of the interval to do the truncation.
But notice that $\phi''$ is exactly the same size as the amplitude (this isn't there when estimating the undifferentiated Bessel function)! So there is an additional cancellation between the amplitude and the width that the naive application does not capture.
In this case you can of course do this by hand more carefully, or you can do a change of variables.
Write
$$ I(\nu,x) = \int_{0}^\pi \exp(i(x\sin(t) - \nu t)) \sin(t) ~dt $$
we do a change of variables with $y = \cos(t)$ so $dy = -\sin(t) dt$
$$\label{eq:main}\tag{*} I(\mu x, x) = \int_{-1}^1 \exp(ix(\sqrt{1-y^2} - \mu \cos^{-1}(y))) ~dy $$
Writing $\eta =\sqrt{1-y^2} - \mu\cos^{-1}(y)$ we have
$$ \eta' = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}(\mu - y)$$
Split the integration into $\int_{-1}^{\mu-\delta}$, $\int_{\mu-\delta}^{\mu+\delta}$, and $\int_{\mu+\delta}^{1}$. In the first and third piece we have $|\eta'| \geq \delta$ and so the integral is bounded by $(x\delta)^{-1}$. The middle term has width $2\delta$ and so has the trivial bound $2\delta$. Optimizing gives $\delta = x^{-1/2}$ and overall uniform rate $x^{-1/2}$.
I suspect \eqref{eq:main} also allows you to show that this is sharp using standard stationary phase arguments.

The following is a generalized version of the van der Corput lemma that can be applied to the current circumstance.

Thm Consider the integral $I(x) = \int_a^b A(s) \exp(ix \phi(s)) ~ds$. Suppose $\phi'' |_{(a,b)} > 0$ and there exists $K > 0$ such that $|A(s)| \leq K \phi''(s)$ for all $s\in [a,b]$, then $|I(x)| \lesssim \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ with the implicit constant depending only on $\|A\|_\infty, \|A'\|_{1}$, and $K$.

Proof: Since $\phi''$ is signed, the function $\phi'$ is increasing and has at most one root in $[a,b]$. Let $J\subseteq [a,b]$ be the interval $\{s | -\delta \leq \phi'(s) \leq \delta\}$ for some $\delta$ to be determined later. The set $[a,b]\setminus J$ the union of at most two intervals, on each of which $|\phi'|$ has a lower bound, and hence we can apply the standard van der Corput lemma to conclude that there exists a universal constant $C$ which is independent of $a,b, A, \phi$ such that for all $x > 0$
$$ \Big|\int_{[a,b]\setminus J} A(s) \exp(ix \phi(s)) ~ds \Big| \leq \frac{C}{\delta x} \Big[ \|A\|_{\infty} + \|A'\|_{1} \Big] $$
On the other hand
$$ \Big| \int_J A(s) \exp(i x \phi(s)) ~ds \Big| \leq \int_J |A(s)| ~ds \leq K \int_J \phi''(s) ~ds = 2K \delta $$
Hence summing and optimizing shows that
$$ |I(x)| \leq \frac{\tilde{C}}{\sqrt{x}} \Big[ \|A\|_\infty + \|A'\|_1 + K \Big]. $$

The previous theorem can be further optimized. We can replace the assumption that $\phi''$ is signed by the assumption that the set $\{\phi'' \neq 0\}$ has finitely many connected components. In this case, the same conclusion hold, except that the implicit constant will depend also on the number of connected components of $\{\phi'' \neq 0\}$.

Thank you! this is even better than a reference to existing literature. But I still think this should be well known to experts

Btw it seems that $J'\nu(\nu)\sim \int_0^\pi \exp(i\nu(\sin t-t))\sin t dt\sim\nu^{-2/3}$ decays faster. This means that sharpness does not occur at $x\sim\nu$ as it happens for $J\nu$

@PieroD'Ancona: right, when $x \approx \nu$ you have that the critical point for $x \sin t - \nu t$ is when $t \approx 0$, for which you get the amplitude gain. But try for example $\nu = 0$. In this case $\phi'(t) = 0$ uniquely at $t = \pi/2$ and $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$ so you get $x^{-1/2}$ decay (with probably explicit coefficient if you work at it a bit).

@PieroD'Ancona and yes, I agree that it would be well-known to experts. But since I am neither one nor have my books handy (on sabbatical this year!), it was easier just to try and prove it. // Also, it is well-know that for $\int \exp(i\lambda\phi(t)) A(t) ~dt$, if $\phi'$ has roots only when $A$ has roots, then we still have $O(1/\lambda)$ bounds. I am not sure I actually know of a source where the analogous statement is claimed or written down for the analogous statement where $\phi''$ has roots only when $A$ has roots.

But my guess is that with a little bit of work one can prove that if $\phi''$ has roots only when $A$ has roots then $\int \exp(i\lambda \phi(t)) A(t) dt$ would be $O(\lambda^{-1/2})$.

This is quite reasonable
